# How to write a program to notify me when a website changes in a certain way?

Tags: python, webserver

I'm looking for a step in the right direction -- maybe which languages I would need, or anything else.

I'm wondering how I can write a script to keep watch on a website and notify me, perhaps by email, of when that website makes a specific change. The specific change I want, for example, is when a website posts a job title with a certain keyword.

So, I want an email sent to me when a website posts a job with a certain keyword, like 'intern'. I.e., I'm interested in what language(s) I can use to make a crawler that will visit websites for me and, upon finding something, do something else. What languages/tools would be best?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is a good choice. If I were you, I'd look into [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html), BeautifulSoup4, and [smtplib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html). Those, maybe in combination with some regular expressions should be all you need to complete your project.

Comment: Thank you. Not sure why this being downvoted? Too stupid of a question?

Comment: I think you're supposed to give it a shot first, post some test code, or even some pseudocode. But your question isn't specific enough to help to code at all. Give some of those libraries a try, then post your results.

Comment: Will do. Your answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user1472747: More likely because such a question seems to be open-ended. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask.

Comment: @user1472747: You were probably down-voted because they felt you broke one or more of these _How to Ask_ [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hey! I did it. It works beautifully. I used Python (for the first time), urllib2, and smtpblib. Thanks hyleaus!